# How to access entities within another aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design, data-modeling

I am trying to model the scenario using DDD where we have teams, developers and tasks a team shall do.

Basically, I assume the following:

- `Team` is an entity (as it can change, e.g. by getting new developers on board)
- `Developer` is an entity as well (as it is important which developer did what)
- `Story` is an entity (as it can change, e.g. by booking work items onto the story)
- `Work` is a value object (as it can not change, once it has been done)

What's quite obvious is that `Team` is an aggregate, containing `Developer` entities. Also, `Story` is an aggregate, containing `Work` value objects.

So, in the beginning I am starting with the following code:

```
var team = Team.FoundTeam();
team.WelcomeDeveloper("John Doe");
team.WelcomeDeveloper("Jane Doe");

var story = Story.WriteDownStory("Publish website");
story.AssignTeam(team);
```

So far, so good. Now, in the next step I want to charge work for the story. Basically this could be as easy as:

```
story.ChargeWork(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
```

Unfortunately, now the work needs to be assigned to a developer. And this is my problem: How do I model this? What I can not do is:

```
story.ChargeWork("Jane Doe", new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
```

This would fail if there were two developers with the same name. How do I assign a specific developer entity, without having access to it (as developers can only be accessed using the `Team` aggregate root)?

Any hints on this?

Is my model completely broken, or am I missing something important?

Comment: I see that you've tagged the question as 'data-modeling'. This is a hint your mindset tells you: you're modeling data (state) instead of modeling business process aka behavior i.e DDD.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This is more valuable than it seems at first sight, hence +1 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could work with ID's as reference.

```
var jane = developer.findByName('Jane Doe');
story.ChargeWork(jane.id, new TimeSpan(2,0,0));
```

Comment: But then I'd expose an entity from the `Team` aggregate to the outside, wouldn't I?

Comment: No - domain driven design prohibits an object holding an _object reference_ to an entity inside another aggregate.  This does not mean you cannot store a reference to the object's _identity_, which is what this answer does.

Answer (score 1):

No one but the domain expert can tell you if the model is broken, but I can tell you some things that IMO pop out.

A Team is an Aggregate Root (NOT an aggregate) which groups together Developers. However, the definition of Developer in the Team bounded context might mean just an Id and some relevant behavior, that is it's not the same Developer entity which is an Aggregate Root in its own bounded context (outside the team).

Now, it's quite simple for the Team entity to enforce unique developers. Also, I think that the Team should charge developers (still confused what charge means) instead of the Story.

The model should closely follow the real life proces, once you start enforcing technical rules ( X is Entity, Y is value object, I must have a repository etc) you're on the wrong path.

Comment: +1 I think you've hit the nail on the head highlighting Developer in different contexts. It's quite possible that a developer could be working in many teams - in that case the relationship is reversed, where Developer is the aggregate root and contains one or more teams. The OP has already hinted towards bounded contexts - where in the story/work context the developer is simply a name string. I would add that it's usually a good idea to introduce some natural or surrogate key which is consistent across contexts, and might act as a reference key when crossing contexts - as mattwagl suggests..